# Repeat one song plugin not working for Rhythm Box

Tags: rhythmbox

Is this plugin Repeat one song - https://launchpad.net/repeat-one-song working for anyone? (For new versions 2.9+) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Repeat One Song](https://launchpad.net/repeat-one-song)

*for rhythmbox 2.96-2.98*

[image]

*for rhythmbox 2.99.1 and later*

[image: pic]

From the pictures you can see that an option exists to repeat the selected track when the option is chosen.

To install, I would suggest my PPA (well I would!) where I have packaged it.

See this question and answer for further details:

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)

Start Rhythmbox, enable the *Repeat One Song plugin*: `Edit --> Plugins`

Answer (score 3):

The Repeat One Song plugin (v0.2) still works in 12.04. It must be installed differently, though.

After downloading the plugin and extracting it to a folder, open your terminal and type

`sudo nautilus`

Navigate to `/usr/share/rhythmbox/plugins` under File System, create a folder named `repeat-one-song` and move the `icon.svg` file in the extracted plugin folder to that location.

Similarly, navigate to `/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins` under File System, create a folder named `repeat-one-song` and move the `repeat-one-song.plugin` and `repeat-one-song.py` files in the extracted plugin folder to that location.

Now you should be able to open Rhythmbox, go to Edit->Plugins, enable "Repeat One Song," and the new repeat icon should appear next to the normal play controls.

Answer (score 1):

I just released Repeat One Song 0.3 for Rhythmbox 2.99+. In order to install, activate and make it work do the following:

Install: download the repeat-one-song_0.3_unstable.tar.gz.tar.gz file from the [downloads](https://launchpad.net/repeat-one-song/+download) section, extract and copy the files into the folder ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/repeat-one-song

Activate: Start Rhythmbox, enable plugin: Edit --> Plugins -> Select "Repeat One Song"

Make it work: Edit (menu) -> Repeat current song, or use the Ctrl + E shortcut.

Ps.: It is still considered "unstable" because of a bug (IMO) on the Gstreamer player. As soon as there is a workround  to it, I will make a better version.